# Spring AMQP listener with varying queues

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am building a spring boot based application, where it listens to the rabbit. You can pass some command line arguments which will make the application listens to various queues. Is there any way to handle this kind of scenario ?

I am referring to [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-amqp/src/main/java/sample/amqp/SampleAmqpSimpleApplication.java) as example.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbit.listener.queue}")
```

and the command line args like:

```
--rabbit.listener.queue=foo
```

See `@RabbitListener.queues()` JavaDocs for more information and Spring Boot [Command Line access](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-command-line-args).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't get the listener names from CLI, I have them loaded from another properties file, how can I handle this.

Comment: ??? Is that your question: " You can pass some command line arguments which will make the application listens to various queues"? Why do we have now a new one about `listener names` and `properties file`? And yeah... Right now it is becoming to be unclear...